# jQuery UI Button Theme

Tags: css, jquery-ui

How can we have the design of a jQuery UI button by just adding the css class?

I have button below:

```
<input class="ui-state-default ui-button" type="button" value="click"/>
```

One thing lacking is the round corner of the jQuery UI button.

Comment: Could you clarify your comment?

Comment: I think what he/she wants is the ability to make something look like a jQuery button, but without using the actual implementation of a standard jQuery UI Button.

Comment: The answer is the `ui-corner-all`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good way.

```
<script>
    $( ".myclass" ).button();
</script>
```

Here is html:

```
<input class="myclass" type="button" value="click"/>
```